# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException when request POST using ajax to spring

Tags: ajax, spring, mime

When I tried to send json js object to spring using method 'POST', I encounter the following error

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void ray.hobin.qbank.QuestionController.insertQuestion(ray.hobin.qbank.object.Question)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void ray.hobin.qbank.QuestionController.insertQuestion(ray.hobin.qbank.object.Question)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void ray.hobin.qbank.QuestionController.insertQuestion(ray.hobin.qbank.object.Question)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

ajax part

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "question/add",
    data: JSON.stringify(question),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: (msg) => {
        console.log(`Insert Q${key} succeed.`);
        resolve();
    },
    error: () => {
        console.log(`Insert Q${key} failed.`);
        reject();
    }
});
```

controller part

```
@Controller
public class QuestionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/question/add", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
    public void insertQuestion(@RequestBody Question question) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("/question/add");
        logger.info("TTTT" + question.getContent());        
    }
}
```

Question class in JS

```
class Question
{
    constructor(content, contentImgPath, choices, choiceImgPaths, answer, explanation, tags, difficulty) {
        this.content = content
        this.contentImgPath = contentImgPath
        this.choices = choices
        this.choiceImgPaths = choiceImgPaths
        this.answer = answer
        this.explanation = explanation
        this.tags = tags
        this.difficulty = difficulty
    }
}
```

Question class in Java

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Question {
    private Long qid;
    private String content;
    private String contentImgPath;
    private List<String> choices;
    private List<String> choiceImgPaths;
    private String answer;
    private String explanation;
    private List<String> tags;
    private String difficulty;

    public Question() {}

    public Question(String content, String contentImgPath, List<String> choices, List<String> choiceImgPaths,
            String answer, String explanation, List<String> tags, String difficulty) {
        super();
        this.content = content;
        this.contentImgPath = contentImgPath;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.choiceImgPaths = choiceImgPaths;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.explanation = explanation;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

}
```

What am I missing? I cannot figure it out after 3 hours of googling...

Comment: consumes="applicatoin/json" spelling mistake and also change consumes="applicatoin/json" to consumes="application/json; charset=utf-8". there is a mismatch between what you set in ajax call and what you defined in consumes see MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE.  Then another one to consider is @RequestBody , kindly make sure every is in place as part of the request.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to "consumes=MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE", but still not working. But I find something interesting at the request body. I tried to send a list (e.g. choices) and it was, but it is dictionary object when I see it at the request body. Would it matter? then how can I fix it?

Comment: do you mean to say that it was coming as object instead of list of objects ? if that is the case make use of jackson annotations . share the request body sent to comment further

Comment: I send js list as one of json value, and it will be captured by corresponding java list(I think). What I mean was it sends `{0: "c1", 1: "c2", length: 2,…}` instead of `["c1", "c2"]` when I check response body on chrome browser. And I think it's the cause of the error...

Comment: I updated the question :)

Comment: yes it might be .